# Неиспользуемые переменные

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите пожалуйста, читаю книгу Герба Саттера, и он пишет такой код:

```
int a = 10;
a; //для подавления предупреждения о неиспользуемой переменной
```

Вопрос: для чего подавлять это предупреждение? Разве это на что то повлияет?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

К сожалению, информация в этой книге явно устарела. Подавление предупреждения о неиспользованной переменной (или параметре) путем написания выражения, где кроме этой переменной ничего нет, [приведет к появлению предупреждений а бесполезном выражении](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wQJi1a0LBYbku5GN).

Для подавления предупреждения раньше следовало использовать приведение переменной к `void`: `static_cast<void>(a);` (обычно обoрачивается в макрос типа `UNUSED_VAR`). В этом случае [никаких предупреждений не последует](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WpDFA2fLTCh2124q).

В современном С++ появился способ отметить переменную как специально неиспользованную. Для этих целей предусмотрен стандартный аттрибут `maybe_unused`: `[[maybe_unused]] int a = 10;`. И в этом случае [никаких предупреждений не будет](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6Tw0IKgVSzhxJpFl).

Подавлять это предупреждение имеет смысл только в одном случае, когда имеется функция, результат который нельзя игнорировать, но мы *намеренно* хотим это сделать:

```
[[nodiscard]] int foo(void){ return 0; }

int main()
{
   foo(); // warning: result of foo is not used
   int a = foo(); // warning: unused variable a
   [[maybe_unsed]] int a = foo(); // no warnings
}
```

Comment: _«Подавлять это предупреждение имеет смысл только в одном случае»_. Это не так, случаев полно. Можете оригинал предложения по этому атрибуту посмотреть, там парочка приведена. А использование  `[[maybe_unused]] ` в таком виде для `nodiscard` выглядит весьма костыльно, уж лучше старый добрый `(void)`.

Comment: @ixSci Так это у атрибута `maybe_unused` еще есть применения, а для подавления предупреждений о неиспользованной переменной других подходящих случаев нет. Подавлять это предупреждение, когда переменная в дальнейшем может использоваться или нет в блоке условной компиляции (например считаем что-то во временной переменной, а потом используем ее в `assert`), не следует. В этом случае ее следует также заключать в блок условной компиляции. И уж конечно костыльно всегда было именно приведение к `void`.

Comment: Так они ничего не сделали для того, чтобы убрать костыль с `void()`, `[[maybe_unused]]` покрывает лишь часть случаев, он не покрывает совершенно то, что покрывается `Q_UNUSED` и прочими. В частности, он никак не взаимодействует с `[[nodiscard]]`. Ну а случаи другие есть: к примеру, есть макрос, который создаёт внутри себя объект, который потом можно использовать, а можно и не использовать. Таких макросов полно в библиотеках, и никто не побежит их сейчас же переписывать под C++17.

Answer (score 1):

Исправлю ответ, а то по комментариям не понятно.

1. Да, компилятор её не отбросит из бинарного кода в том случае если установлены соответствующие настройки оптимизации.
2. Если вы используете gcc то, воспользуйтесь флагом -Wunused-*, он покажет что в коде есть неиспользуемая переменная - этот флаг входит в флаг -Wall

Comment: Вот как раз `-Wunused` просто подавит предупреждение, но переменная из кода скорее всего будет выброшена (в зависимости от уровня оптимизации).

Comment: Верно, в зависимости от оптимизации.

Comment: Тоесть если у меня есть функция, в теле которой я пишу: B* pb = p; то если я больше не упомяну в коде указатель pb, то операция B* pb = p; не выполнится?

Comment: Скорее всего компилятор её отбросит. Нужно смотреть ассемблерный листинг и флаги компиляции.

Comment: Это неверный ответ, наличие или отсутствие предупреждения никак не влияет на выбрасывание / невыбрасывание переменной компилятором. А опция `-Wunused` *включает* предупреждение о неиспользованных переменных.